# How can I add a method for rotate the element automatically at page load?

Tags: javascript, animation

In my index page I have a cube built with css and animated with js, at the moment I rotate the cube by clicking the mouse and drag. I want also at the load of page that the cube automatically rotate random slowly and at the click take the controll. How can I do that, after code my try:

```
var events = new Events();
events.add = function(obj) {
  obj.events = { };
}
events.implement = function(fn) {
  fn.prototype = Object.create(Events.prototype);
}

function Events() {
  this.events = { };
}
Events.prototype.on = function(name, fn) {
  var events = this.events[name];
  if (events == undefined) {
    this.events[name] = [ fn ];
    this.emit('event:on', fn);
  } else {
    if (events.indexOf(fn) == -1) {
      events.push(fn);
      this.emit('event:on', fn);
    }
  }
  return this;
}
Events.prototype.once = function(name, fn) {
  var events = this.events[name];
  fn.once = true;
  if (!events) {
    this.events[name] = [ fn ];
    this.emit('event:once', fn);
  } else {
    if (events.indexOf(fn) == -1) {
      events.push(fn);
      this.emit('event:once', fn);
    }
  }
  return this;
}
Events.prototype.emit = function(name, args) {
  var events = this.events[name];
  if (events) {
    var i = events.length;
    while(i--) {
      if (events[i]) {
        events[i].call(this, args);
        if (events[i].once) {
          delete events[i];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return this;
}
Events.prototype.unbind = function(name, fn) {
  if (name) {
    var events = this.events[name];
    if (events) {
      if (fn) {
        var i = events.indexOf(fn);
        if (i != -1) {
          delete events[i];
        }
      } else {
        delete this.events[name];
      }
    }
  } else {
    delete this.events;
    this.events = { };
  }
  return this;
}

var userPrefix;

var prefix = (function () {
  var styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, ''),
    pre = (Array.prototype.slice
      .call(styles)
      .join('') 
      .match(/-(moz|webkit|ms)-/) || (styles.OLink === '' && ['', 'o'])
    )[1],
    dom = ('WebKit|Moz|MS|O').match(new RegExp('(' + pre + ')', 'i'))[1];
  userPrefix = {
    dom: dom,
    lowercase: pre,
    css: '-' + pre + '-',
    js: pre[0].toUpperCase() + pre.substr(1)
  };
})();

function bindEvent(element, type, handler) {
  if(element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
  } else {
    element.attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
  }
}

function Viewport(data) {
  events.add(this);

  var self = this;

  this.element = data.element;
  this.fps = data.fps;
  this.sensivity = data.sensivity;
  this.sensivityFade = data.sensivityFade;
  this.touchSensivity = data.touchSensivity;
  this.speed = data.speed;

  this.lastX = 0;
  this.lastY = 0;
  this.mouseX = 0;
  this.mouseY = 0;
  this.distanceX = 0;
  this.distanceY = 0;
  this.positionX = 1122;
  this.positionY = 136;
  this.torqueX = 0;
  this.torqueY = 0;

  this.down = false;
  this.upsideDown = false;

  this.previousPositionX = 0;
  this.previousPositionY = 0;

  this.currentSide = 0;
  this.calculatedSide = 0;


  bindEvent(document, 'mousedown', function() {
    self.down = true;
  });

  bindEvent(document, 'mouseup', function() {
    self.down = false;
  });
  
  bindEvent(document, 'keyup', function() {
    self.down = false;
  });

  bindEvent(document, 'mousemove', function(e) {
    self.mouseX = e.pageX;
    self.mouseY = e.pageY;
  });

  bindEvent(document, 'touchstart', function(e) {

    self.down = true;
    e.touches ? e = e.touches[0] : null;
    self.mouseX = e.pageX / self.touchSensivity;
    self.mouseY = e.pageY / self.touchSensivity;
    self.lastX  = self.mouseX;
    self.lastY  = self.mouseY;
  });

  bindEvent(document, 'touchmove', function(e) {
    if(e.preventDefault) { 
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(e.touches.length == 1) {

      e.touches ? e = e.touches[0] : null;

      self.mouseX = e.pageX / self.touchSensivity;
      self.mouseY = e.pageY / self.touchSensivity;

    }
  });

  bindEvent(document, 'touchend', function(e) {
    self.down = false;
  });


  setInterval(this.animate.bind(this), this.fps);
}

events.implement(Viewport);


Viewport.prototype.animate = function() {

  this.distanceX = (this.mouseX - this.lastX);
  this.distanceY = (this.mouseY - this.lastY);

  this.lastX = this.mouseX;
  this.lastY = this.mouseY;

  if(this.down) {
    this.torqueX = this.torqueX * this.sensivityFade + (this.distanceX * this.speed - this.torqueX) * this.sensivity;
    this.torqueY = this.torqueY * this.sensivityFade + (this.distanceY * this.speed - this.torqueY) * this.sensivity;
  }

  if(Math.abs(this.torqueX) > 1.0 || Math.abs(this.torqueY) > 1.0) {
    if(!this.down) {
      this.torqueX *= this.sensivityFade;
      this.torqueY *= this.sensivityFade;
    }

    this.positionY -= this.torqueY;

    if(this.positionY > 360) {
      this.positionY -= 360;
    } else if(this.positionY < 0) {
      this.positionY += 360;
    }

    if(this.positionY > 90 && this.positionY < 270) {
      this.positionX -= this.torqueX;

      if(!this.upsideDown) {
        this.upsideDown = true;
        this.emit('upsideDown', { upsideDown: this.upsideDown });
      }

    } else {

      this.positionX += this.torqueX;

      if(this.upsideDown) {
        this.upsideDown = false;
        this.emit('upsideDown', { upsideDown: this.upsideDown });
      }
    }

    if(this.positionX > 360) {
      this.positionX -= 360;
    } else if(this.positionX < 0) {
      this.positionX += 360;
    }

    if(!(this.positionY >= 46 && this.positionY <= 130) && !(this.positionY >= 220 && this.positionY <= 308)) {
      if(this.upsideDown) {
        if(this.positionX >= 42 && this.positionX <= 130) {
          this.calculatedSide = 3;
        } else if(this.positionX >= 131 && this.positionX <= 223) {
          this.calculatedSide = 2;
        } else if(this.positionX >= 224 && this.positionX <= 314) {
          this.calculatedSide = 5;
        } else {
          this.calculatedSide = 4;
        }
      } else {
        if(this.positionX >= 42 && this.positionX <= 130) {
          this.calculatedSide = 5;
        } else if(this.positionX >= 131 && this.positionX <= 223) {
          this.calculatedSide = 4;
        } else if(this.positionX >= 224 && this.positionX <= 314) {
          this.calculatedSide = 3;
        } else {
          this.calculatedSide = 2;
        }
      }
    } else {
      if(this.positionY >= 46 && this.positionY <= 130) {
        this.calculatedSide = 6;
      }

      if(this.positionY >= 220 && this.positionY <= 308) {
        this.calculatedSide = 1;
      }
    }

    if(this.calculatedSide !== this.currentSide) {
      this.currentSide = this.calculatedSide;
      this.emit('sideChange');
    }

  }

  this.element.style[userPrefix.js + 'Transform'] = 'rotateX(' + this.positionY + 'deg) rotateY(' + this.positionX + 'deg)';

  if(this.positionY != this.previousPositionY || this.positionX != this.previousPositionX) {
    this.previousPositionY = this.positionY;
    this.previousPositionX = this.positionX;

    this.emit('rotate');

  }

}

var viewport = new Viewport({
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('cube')[0],
  fps: 20,
  sensivity: .1,
  sensivityFade: .93,
  speed: 0.5,
  touchSensivity: 1.5
});

function Cube(data) {
  var self = this;

  this.element = data.element;
  this.sides = this.element.getElementsByClassName('side');

  this.viewport = data.viewport;
  // this.viewport.on('rotate', function() {
  //   self.rotateSides();
  // });
  // this.viewport.on('upsideDown', function(obj) {
  //   self.upsideDown(obj);
  // });
  this.viewport.on('sideChange', function() {
    self.sideChange();
  });
}
// Cube.prototype.rotateSides = function() {
//   var viewport = this.viewport;
//   if(viewport.positionY > 90 && viewport.positionY < 270) {
//     this.sides[0].getElementsByClassName('cube-image')[0].style[userPrefix.js + 'Transform'] = 'rotate(' + (viewport.positionX + viewport.torqueX) + 'deg)';
//     this.sides[5].getElementsByClassName('cube-image')[0].style[userPrefix.js + 'Transform'] = 'rotate(' + -(viewport.positionX + 180 + viewport.torqueX) + 'deg)';
//   } else {
//     this.sides[0].getElementsByClassName('cube-image')[0].style[userPrefix.js + 'Transform'] = 'rotate(' + (viewport.positionX - viewport.torqueX) + 'deg)';
//     this.sides[5].getElementsByClassName('cube-image')[0].style[userPrefix.js + 'Transform'] = 'rotate(' + -(viewport.positionX + 180 - viewport.torqueX) + 'deg)';
//   }
// }
// Cube.prototype.upsideDown = function(obj) {

//   var deg = (obj.upsideDown == true) ? '180deg' : '0deg';
//   var i = 5;

//   while(i > 0 && --i) {
//     this.sides[i].getElementsByClassName('cube-image')[0].style[userPrefix.js + 'Transform'] = 'rotate(' + deg + ')';
//   }
// }
Cube.prototype.sideChange = function() {

  for(var i = 0; i < this.sides.length; ++i) {
    this.sides[i].getElementsByClassName('cube-image')[0].className = 'cube-image';    
  }

  this.sides[this.viewport.currentSide - 1].getElementsByClassName('cube-image')[0].className = 'cube-image active';

}

// Cube.prototype.autoMove = function() {
//   var viewport = this.viewport;
//   this.sides[0].getElementsByClassName('cube-image')[0].style[userPrefix.js + 'Transform'] = 'rotate(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) + 'deg)';
//   this.sides[5].getElementsByClassName('cube-image')[0].style[userPrefix.js + 'Transform'] = 'rotate(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) + 'deg)';
// }

// this.autoMove();

new Cube({
  viewport: viewport,
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('cube')[0]
});
```

I tried to make something like this:

```
Viewport.prototype.autoMove = document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    this.positionX = 0;
    this.positionY = 0;
    while (this.positionX <= 1122 && this.positionY <= 136) {
      this.element.style[userPrefix.js + 'Transform'] = 'rotateX(' + this.positionY + 'deg) rotateY(' + this.positionX + 'deg)';

      this.positionX++;
      this.positionY++;
    }
  })
```

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Cube Project</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="theTitle">CUBE</h1>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="viewport">
      <div class="cube">
        <div class="side">
          <div class="cube-image"><h2><a class="cube-link" href="#">BLA BLA BLA,<br> BLA BLA BLA.</a></h2></div>
        </div>
        <div class="side">
          <div class="cube-image">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="side">
          <div class="cube-image">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="side">
          <div class="cube-image">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="side">
          <div class="cube-image">5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="side">
          <div class="cube-image active">6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share the html code

Comment: I added it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an animation style to the `cube` element

```
@keyframes rotate{
  to{ transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.cube{
  animation: rotate 4.5s linear infinite; 
}
```

Comment: It works but with some lags when I try to move it with mouse and with a frame block when the animation restart

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomMoves=serInterval(rotateRandomly,100);

function rotateRandomly() { ... }
```

on click:

```
if(randomMoves!=NULL) clearInterval(randomMoves);
randomMoves=NULL;
```

Of course you should use requestAnimationFrame instead, but this is so simple...

Comment: ok but I need to put this method in the Viewport ?

Comment: @p.perfetto993 you should start the interval at dom ready event (does not matter where you put it), and then the interval function can call any method you put in the ViewPort at regular intervals.

Comment: @p.perfetto993
`savedInterval=setInterval(this.animate.bind(this), this.fps);`
At mousedown:
`clearInterval(savedInterval);`